# Leaflet & Esri-Leaflet: JSON objects not drawing correctly when using 'fields' filter

Tags: leaflet, esri-leaflet

I am working with Leaflet 0.7.3 and [esri-leaflet beta.6](http://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/api-reference/). Using [L.esri.Layers.FeatureLayer](http://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/api-reference/layers/feature-layer.html) works fine until I add the fields filter. At that point, the geojson objects draw sporadically (mostly not at all). I might see one or two shapes on the screen.

Example code at http://codepen.io/BBurnworth/pen/fhBrG/

Lines 32-36:

```
 //The line below works.
 var parcels = new L.esri.Layers.FeatureLayer(url + '24');

 // **The below line works (Checked JSON attributes in firebug) but the parcels flicker and don't display properly**
 // var parcels = new L.esri.Layers.FeatureLayer(url + '24', { fields: "CITY" });
```

Is this a bug or am I leaving something out? The JSON (in Firebug) reads correctly, with the geometry data coming in. It just doesn't draw correctly.

I would love for someone to point out something simple that I am missing. I would rather  fetch just the bare minimum of data and then use the [tasks.IdentifyFeatures](http://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/api-reference/tasks/identify-features.html) to get the attribute data when the user wants it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a couple things here...

1. that constructor option expects an [array](http://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/api-reference/layers/feature-layer.html)
2. at a minimum, you have to include the OBJECTID field in that array in order for everything to work on the clientside as it should.

   { fields: ["OBJECTID", "CITY"] }

we should probably be handling that for people.  i'll look into it.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pjEtD

Comment: TY. John, I have another issue relating to the tasks.identifyFeatures not accepting [34.98,-90] but will accept L.latLng(34.98,-90). Should I post here on SE or is there a more appropriate forum?

Comment: my pleasure.  here is fine, as is the 'esri-leaflet' space in geonet https://geonet.esri.com/thread/113120

Comment: i added a warning for developers when no known ObjectId field can be found which should be included in beta7 https://github.com/Esri/esri-leaflet/issues/366